# Difference between 'could have to go' and 'could have had to go'?

Tags: word-meaning, vocabulary, word-difference

I am confused between

> I could have to go
>
> I could have had to go
>
> I can have to go
>
> I can have had to go

Can anyone explain meaning of both with better and easy understanding example.

Comment: These sentences don't sound OK.  I think we don't use can/could before have/had + to-infi itive.

Comment: @Khan: you certainly can use could with have. It expresses the possibility of a requirement.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=may+have+to+go%2Cmight+have+to+go%2Cmight+have+had+to+go%2C+could+have+to+go%2C+could+have+had+to+go&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmay%20have%20to%20go%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmight%20have%20to%20go%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmight%20have%20had%20to%20go%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccould%20have%20to%20go%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

> I could have to go

It is possible that I may be required to go. That's the auxiliary *have* in its modal sense (*have to*), indicating a requirement, **along with** the modal *could* indicating possibility.

> I could have had to go

It was possible that I might have been required to go. Just the same as before, but in the present perfect, basically.

> I can have to go
>   I can have had to go

These don't work.